# If a false positive rate of α is desired, what is the acceptable range of false positives one would expect from a sample size of n?

Tags: measurement, range, false-positive-rate

For instance, suppose I design a test to have a false positive rate of 5%. I am going to perform this test on what is assumed to be an all negative population. If my sample size was 20, I would expect 1 false positive.

What is the range of false positives I could actually get that is consistent with the design (5% false positive rate) and assumption (population is all negative)?

In other words, if I get 2 positives, do I begin to question the design or assumptions? If not, when do I? 3, 4, 5? 0?

How would one calculate this range in general?

I had trouble finding this answer on Google. What is the term(s) I should be searching for?

Comment: Proportion test! What are the acceptance and rejection regions for $H_0: p=0.05$ vs $H_a: p>0.05$? (Casella/Berger uses “acceptance region” no matter how much we stress not accepting a null hypothesis.)

Comment: The terminology 'false positive rate' has been so often abused that it I don't believe it can be used without clarification. Do you mean P(Positive and No Disease) or P(Positive | No Disease) = 1 - Specificity?  Best to use Sensitivity and Specificity in Google.

Answer (score 1):

The actual negatives used in your trial can be considered as a random sample from a larger population of actual negatives. Your model assigns the label "true" with a certain probability p. This is a Bernoulli trial. So you need to know the confidence interval for estimating p based on an observed proportion.

[This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) tells you how to do this.

Comment: Going off your answer, I found this calculator: http://www.statskingdom.com/41_proportion_confidence_interval.html However, it answers the following question, "given this many trials and this many successes, what is the CI for the true rate?" Instead, I'd like the reverse of this: "Given this many trials and a hypothesized rate of r, what is the range of successes I can expect to see 95% of the time?" But what I found with your help can get me there, just not directly.